# Use a Regex in SQL statement to extract several strings - Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to extract some strings from the VAL column, according the regex furhter below in bold. This is an example of the data I have in source :

```
Table1
-----------------
ID         VAL       
-----------------
1          GR-RDE
2          GR-RZA-RDE
3          GR-RZA-RDE_RZA
4          GR-RGS
5          GR-RZA-OR-ORC
6          GR-RZA-RDE-OR-ORC_RZA
```

Desired result :

```
> Output
-----------------
ID         RESULT       
-----------------
1          RDE
2          RZA
2          RDE
3          RZA
3          RDE
4          RGS
5          RZA
5          OR
6          RZA
6          RDE
6          OR
```

To do that, I've done this regex :
**(?<=-)(RDE|RZA|RGS|OR)(?![A-Z])**

- (?<=-) : checks that the character before is '-'
- (RDE|RZA|RGS|OR) :    search for 'RDE', 'RZA', 'RGS', 'OR' strings
- (?![A-Z]) : ignore the string if    it's followed by a letter

The regex works perfectly and it ignores all the unwhanted parts :
[image: Regex to handle the process]

My problem is that I don't find the way to use this regex in a SQL statement (Oracle database). I've tried to perform a test with something like this, which returns Null :

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL,'(?<=-)(RDE|RZA|RGS|OR)(?![A-Z])') from Table1;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that Oracle doesn't support lookaround :(

Comment: Ok so maybe I need to find another way to do this, without using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac251/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( ID, VAL ) AS
SELECT 1, 'GR-RDE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'GR-RZA-RDE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'GR-RZA-RDE_RZA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'GR-RGS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'GR-RZA-OR-ORC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'GR-RZA-RDE-OR-ORC_RZA' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH words ( id, val, lvl, str, maxlvl ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         val,
         1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '[A-Z]+', 1, 1 ),
         REGEXP_COUNT( val, '[A-Z]+' )
  FROM   table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         val,
         lvl + 1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '[A-Z]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
         maxlvl
  FROM   words
  WHERE  lvl < maxlvl
)
SELECT id, str, lvl
FROM   words
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac251/11/0)**:

```
| ID | STR | LVL |
|----|-----|-----|
|  1 |  GR |   1 |
|  1 | RDE |   2 |
|  2 |  GR |   1 |
|  2 | RZA |   2 |
|  2 | RDE |   3 |
|  3 |  GR |   1 |
|  3 | RZA |   2 |
|  3 | RDE |   3 |
|  3 | RZA |   4 |
|  4 |  GR |   1 |
|  4 | RGS |   2 |
|  5 |  GR |   1 |
|  5 | RZA |   2 |
|  5 |  OR |   3 |
|  5 | ORC |   4 |
|  6 |  GR |   1 |
|  6 | RZA |   2 |
|  6 | RDE |   3 |
|  6 |  OR |   4 |
|  6 | ORC |   5 |
|  6 | RZA |   6 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t.id, w.COLUMN_VALUE AS str
FROM   Table1 t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.val, '[A-Z]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.val, '[A-Z]+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) w
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac251/11/1)**:

```
| ID | STR |
|----|-----|
|  1 |  GR |
|  1 | RDE |
|  2 |  GR |
|  2 | RZA |
|  2 | RDE |
|  3 |  GR |
|  3 | RZA |
|  3 | RDE |
|  3 | RZA |
|  4 |  GR |
|  4 | RGS |
|  5 |  GR |
|  5 | RZA |
|  5 |  OR |
|  5 | ORC |
|  6 |  GR |
|  6 | RZA |
|  6 | RDE |
|  6 |  OR |
|  6 | ORC |
|  6 | RZA |
```